# org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaForm.schemaValueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaForm;

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, web-services, tomcat

I'm started this week trying to create webservices using Eclipse and Tomcat v8. I wasn't even able to see the list on the services option from Tomcat, I've included the XmlSchema-1.4.7 on my libs and got this list of "Faulty Services":

This was the only thing that I've found relevant on the console: 
`[INFO] org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaForm.schemaValueOf(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaForm;`

Can someone help me with this?
I tried to use XmlSchema-1.4.7 or xmlschema-core-2.0 but I kept getting the same result.

Answer (score 2):

No XmlSchema-1.4.7 won't work, it looks like the interface has changed.

Download the latest XmlSchema, now xmlschema-core from Apache (2.2.1)

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/xmlschema/

Open the compressed file 
 xmlschema-core-2.2.1-bin.zip

and put the xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar into the WEB-INF/lib